# React/Typescript forwardRef types for an element which returns either an input or textArea

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-forwardref

I'm trying to create a generic text input component for our application using react and typescript. I want it to be able to either be an input element or a textarea element based on a given prop. So it looks somewhat like this:

```
import {TextArea, Input} from 'ourComponentLibrary'

export const Component = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const Element = props.type === 'textArea' ? TextArea : Input

  return (
    <Element ref={ref} />
  )
})
```

This code works fine. However, when trying to incorporate types it becomes a little dicey. The ref type should be either `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement` based on the passed `type` prop. In my head, it would look something like this:

```
interface Props {
  ...
}

export const Component = forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement,
  Props
>((props, ref) => {
  ...
});
```

However I know this isn't exactly what I need. Hence, the error:
`Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLTextAreaElement': cols, rows, textLength, wrap`

In summary, I want the types to align so that if the `type` prop is `textArea` then the `ref` type should be `HTMLTextAreaElement`, and if the type prop is `input` then the ref type should be `HTMLInputAreaElement`

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: quick question before i investigate this further. what is the end result you are actually seeking by using a single component for both textarea and input ? for me it seems like separating them each to its own component is the better approach

Comment: You are basically trying to do a runtime type check at compile time, which isn't possible. `Component` is undecided about the type, hence your runtime check on the prop inside the Component. You can only hard cast the type to be either `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement` when you know exactly what type it will be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this by no means fixes the problem with `React.forwardProps`, an alternative would be to work around it and instead utilize an `innerRef` property. Then you can enforce types on the `innerRef` property. Achieves the same result that you want, but with flexible typing, less overhead, and no instantiation.

**Working demo:**

[image: Edit Typescript - Switch Component]

---

**components/Label/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FC, LabelProps } from "~types";

/*
  Field label for form elements

  @param {string} name - form field name
  @param {string} label - form field label 
  @returns {JSX.Element}
*/
const Label: FC<LabelProps> = ({ name, label }) => (
  <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
    {label}&#58;
  </label>
);

export default Label;
```

**components/Fields/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Label from "../Label";
import { FC, InputProps, TextAreaProps } from "~types";

/*
  Field elements for a form that are conditionally rendered by a fieldType
  of "input" or "textarea".

  @param {Object} props - properties for an input or textarea
  @returns {JSX.Element | null} 
*/
const Field: FC<InputProps | TextAreaProps> = (props) => {
  switch (props.fieldType) {
    case "input":
      return (
        <>
          <Label name={props.name} label={props.label} />
          <input
            ref={props.innerRef}
            name={props.name}
            className={props.className}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            type={props.type}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
          />
        </>
      );
    case "textarea":
      return (
        <>
          <Label name={props.name} label={props.label} />
          <textarea
            ref={props.innerRef}
            name={props.name}
            className={props.className}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            rows={props.rows}
            cols={props.cols}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
          />
        </>
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default Field;
```

**components/Form/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Field from "../Fields";
import { FormEvent, FC, EventTargetNameValue } from "~types";

const initialState = {
  email: "",
  name: "",
  background: ""
};

const Form: FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
  const emailRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const nameRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const bgRef = React.useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { name, value } }: EventTargetNameValue) => {
      setState((s) => ({ ...s, [name]: value }));
    },
    []
  );

  const handleReset = React.useCallback(() => {
    setState(initialState);
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(
    (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const alertMessage = Object.values(state).some((v) => !v)
        ? "Must fill out all form fields before submitting!"
        : JSON.stringify(state, null, 4);

      alert(alertMessage);
    },
    [state]
  );

  return (
    <form className="uk-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        innerRef={emailRef}
        label="Email"
        className="uk-input"
        fieldType="input"
        type="email"
        name="email"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter email..."
        value={state.email}
      />
      <Field
        innerRef={nameRef}
        label="Name"
        className="uk-input"
        fieldType="input"
        type="text"
        name="name"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter name..."
        value={state.name}
      />
      <Field
        innerRef={bgRef}
        label="Background"
        className="uk-textarea"
        fieldType="textarea"
        rows={5}
        name="background"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter background..."
        value={state.background}
      />
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
        type="button"
        onClick={handleReset}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <button
        style={{ float: "right" }}
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**types/index.ts**

```
import type {
  FC,
  ChangeEvent,
  RefObject as Ref,
  FormEvent,
  ReactText
} from "react";

// custom utility types that can be reused
type ClassName = { className?: string };
type InnerRef<T> = { innerRef?: Ref<T> };
type OnChange<T> = { onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<T>) => void };
type Placeholder = { placeholder?: string };
type Value<T> = { value: T };

// defines a destructured event in a callback
export type EventTargetNameValue = {
  target: {
    name: string;
    value: string;
  };
};

/*
  Utility interface that constructs typings based upon passed in arguments

  @param {HTMLElement} E - type of HTML Element that is being rendered
  @param {string} F - the fieldType to be rendered ("input" or "textarea")
  @param {string} V - the type of value the field expects to be (string, number, etc)
*/
interface FieldProps<E, F, V>
  extends LabelProps,
    ClassName,
    Placeholder,
    OnChange<E>,
    InnerRef<E>,
    Value<V> {
  fieldType: F;
}

// defines props for a "Label" component
export interface LabelProps {
  name: string;
  label: string;
}

// defines props for an "input" element by extending the FieldProps interface
export interface InputProps
  extends FieldProps<HTMLInputElement, "input", ReactText> {
  type: "text" | "number" | "email" | "phone";
}

// defines props for an "textarea" element by extending the FieldProps interface
export interface TextAreaProps
  extends FieldProps<HTMLTextAreaElement, "textarea", string> {
  cols?: number;
  rows?: number;
}

// exporting React types for reusability
export type { ChangeEvent, FC, FormEvent };
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./index.css";

render(<Form />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Huh I thought that this wouldn't work and that `forwardRef()` was necessary to pass refs to children. That begs the question, what exactly is the point of using `forwardRef()` if this more straightforward approach will work? BTW nice example, but it would be good to have more explanation of what's going on aside from just the working code demo though. :)

Comment: The innerRef workaround method has been around for awhile (before 16.3 when forwardProps wasn't available), but it essentially does the same. My assumption is that forwardRef was established to provide a standardized restrictive pattern of passing down a ref to a child. To avoid confusion, it ensures the `ref` is clearly separated from `props`. In addition, some might find `innerRef` to be an ambiguous property since it's not an official way to attach a ref to an element. Updated the above with notes, if anything else isn't clear let me know.

Comment: Awarded the bounty! Appreciated your solution @jered, but this feels more idiomatic to react. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm really late to answer this, but this is how I solved this problem.  Maybe this will help someone else someday.

```
type InputElement = 'input' | 'textarea'

export type InputProps<E extends InputElement> = {
    multiline: E extends 'textarea' ? true : false
    /* rest of props */
}

const Component = React.forwardRef(function Component<E extends InputElement>(
    props: InputProps<E>,
    ref: React.Ref<HTMLElementTagNameMap[E] | null>,
) {
```

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for answering this question! When answering, it's helpful to include an explanation as to how and why the code works. Feel free to [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66052438/edit) to include additional details.

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky one, and the only viable way I can think to do this is with a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Basically, we have to create a function that will itself return one type of component or the other depending on what argument its passed.

```js
// Overload signature #1
function MakeInput(
  type: "textArea"
): React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  TextAreaProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>
>;
// Overload signature #2
function MakeInput(
  type: "input"
): React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  InputProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
>;
// Function declaration
function MakeInput(type: "textArea" | "input") {
  if (type === "textArea") {
    const ret = React.forwardRef<HTMLTextAreaElement, TextAreaProps>(
      (props, ref) => {
        return <TextArea {...props} ref={ref} />;
      }
    );
    return ret;
  } else {
    const ret = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>((props, ref) => {
      return <Input {...props} ref={ref} />;
    });
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Then, instantiate the component type you want to render by calling the higher order component function `MakeInput()` with the "type" of the component:

```js
export default function App() {
  const textAreaRef = React.useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const MyTextArea = MakeInput("textArea");
  const MyInput = MakeInput("input");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MyTextArea value={"Foo"} ref={textAreaRef} />
      <MyInput value={"Bar"} ref={inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, this may feel "unsatisfying" because this is roughly equivalent to doing a conditional check here to see what type of component to render based on `type`, just abstracted away into a function. But, you *can't* render a magical `<MyTextAreaOrInputComponent />` and get full type checking on *both* its `props` and `ref` attributes. And for that, you'll have to blame React itself, because the `ref` prop, like `key` and possibly some other props, are very very special and treated uniquely by React, which is exactly what necessitates `React.forwardRef()` in the first place.

But if you think about it, in practical terms you're still getting the prop type checking that you are looking for, it's just that you add an extra step of calling `MakeInput()` to determine the component type. So instead of writing this:

```js
return <Component type="textArea" ref={textAreaRef} />
```

You're writing this:

```js
const MyComponent = MakeInput("textArea");

return <MyComponent ref={textAreaRef} />
```

In both cases, you clearly *must* know the value of *both* `type` and `ref` at the time you are writing your code. The former case is impossible to get working (to my knowledge) because of the way `React.forwardRef()` works. But the latter case *is* possible, and gives you the exact same level of type checking, just with the extra step.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pare-pqmfu?file=/src/App.tsx

Note: play around with the sandbox above and see how even though `<Input/>` has an additional prop `extraInputValue` compared to `<TextArea/>`, the higher order component handles it gracefully. Also note that calling `MakeInput()` with either valid string value to create a component results in the expected and proper prop type checking.

Edit: Another illustration of how a "magic bullet" component vs. using a HOC are functionally identical in terms of type checking, since in your scenario you know both the `type` and what HTML element the `ref` should represent at pre-compile-time, you could literally just do this IIFE which contains the same amount of information:

```js
  return <div>
      {(function(){
        const C = MakeInput("textArea");
        return <C value={"Baz"} ref={textAreaRef} />
      })()}
  </div>;
```